# use of two queries in a model of MVC

Tags: php, html, sql

```
public function getotherclothdetail($id)
{
    $qry1 = "SELECT rentprice from cloth_table where id = '$id' ";
    $result2 = $this->fetch($qry1);
    $qry = "SELECT cloth_table.*, user_table.email from cloth_table, user_table WHERE cloth_table.owner_id = user_table.id And cloth_table.price = $result2[0]['rentprice'] ";    
    $result = $this->fetch($qry);   
    return $result;
}
```

i want to display others cloth details from cloth_table where price is equal to selected cloth id price. help me out.

Comment: What is the table structure? Is that all you have tried? What does fetch do? Is it an alias for the PDO fetch? What problems are you having?

Comment: Try changing `cloth_table.price = $result2[0]['rentprice'] "` to `cloth_table.price = ".$result2[0]['rentprice']` - BUT also you should be using prepared statements and bind values.

Comment: Alternatively, you can also use a nested query : `$qry = "SELECT cloth_table.*, user_table.email from cloth_table, user_table WHERE cloth_table.owner_id = user_table.id And cloth_table.price = (SELECT rentprice from cloth_table where cloth_table.id = '$id' )";`

Comment: @kchason i have problem in array. i think $result2[0]['renrprice'] will take value on running qry1. but problem has been solved. thanks for your help

Comment: @Hassan thanks for help. problem has been solved. i just forget this way, mybad